# filter files with find command, sort output into directories

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/env bash

MONTHS=(Jan Feb Mar ...)

for month in ${MONTHS[@]}
do
    if [ ! -d $month ]; then
        mkdir $month
    fi

    # below is the code I would like to improve upon
    find ./ -iname "*$month*.pdf" -type f | xargs mv $month/
done
```

What I was trying to do, was:

1) Using the variable `MONTHS`, loop through each iteration by first checking if a directory with such a name exists, and if it doesn't, make a directory with the name (so when `month=Jan`, if `Jan` directory doesn't exist, it would make a `Jan` directory. if it does exist, proceed to next line, etc).

2) Find files in the current directory that has the month variable in its name (so it looks for all files with the word `Jan` in the file name, `Feb`, `Mar`, etc).

3) Pipe the output by moving it to the directory with the same month variable name (so all `Jan` files get moved to the `Jan` directory, `Feb` files into the `Feb` directory, etc).

I've been trying to code the last `find` command line for quite awhile, I checked most of the questions that are relevant however the most I've gotten was an error saying I cant move `fileThatHasMonthInTheName.pdf` into its own subdirectory `sameLongFilename` or that it's trying to move the month folder into itself.

My goal is to: find files that have the month name in the filename, pipe it to the directory who has the same month name

---

Command that produced the output by @thanasisp

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$month*" | xargs -I{} mv {} $month
```

Comment: Post the code in your question.  We do not want to have to type it locally to try it.  Read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557.

Comment: @Nic3500 sorry about that, i wrote out the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make these modifications

```
MONTHS=( Jan Feb Mar )

for month in ${MONTHS[@]}
do
    mkdir -p $month
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$month*" | xargs -I{} mv {} $month
done
```

- `mkdir -p` will create the dir if not exists
- `find` files should be restricted to `maxdepth 1` so that won't return files previously copied to existing month dirs
- use `xargs` with `-I` in order to process the find output in right position, preserving any arguments with spaces, eg a file named `Jan 01.csv`

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer explains, find does recurse into sub-directories.  My solution is simply to use ls, which does not (it will only show files in the current directory):

```
#!/bin/bash

MONTHS=(Jan Feb Mar ...)

for month in ${MONTHS[@]}
do
    if [ ! -d $month ]; then
        mkdir $month
    fi
    /bin/ls *$month*.pdf | xargs mv -t $month
done
```

I use /bin/ls to make sure I do not carry any alias formatting that some users prefer into the script.

NOTE: I edited the ls command to include the missing *.  It is now `/bin/ls *$month*.pdf` like the OP wanted.

Comment: this gave me an error message saying that I can't access `Jan*`, `Feb*`, etc, files. i was looking mainly to pipe the files present in the current directory but thank you for trying to help me regardless!

Comment: @alxq: sorry, I forgot the prefix * to $month*.pdf.  Fixed.